# bypassing @login_required if it matches my ip on flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

Looking for help I have been racking my brain getting this to work, after lot of reading research I not sure if it possible with the way I have flask built

What I need is a way to bypass login if my ip is found

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    ip = request.remote_addr
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect('home')
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```

```
@app.route("/account")
@login_required
def account():
    return render_template('account.html', title='Account')
```

With the above I have tried
`if request.remote_addr == '127.0.0.1':`  i have applied this to the login

I also added a case on `app.config['LOGIN_DISABLED'] = True` however this changes the over all so security wont work

My Main question is how can I bypass @login_required

is pip flask_login not the best approach

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Add IP section into the user model section, use the database to store all user's IP addresses. And you can find your IP address in the database, then try to give access to that current user, try "if user.ip == 192.168.0.x" redirect to the home page.

Comment: i did get this working based on using the database

`    if current_user.is_authenticated == False:
        try:
            print(request.remote_addr)
            user = User.query.filter_by(ip=request.remote_addr).first()
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect('home')
        except:
            ''` Thank you

Comment: No, no, no. You miss understanding my point. What I'm saying is to if it's your IP address, you don't need to login to access to the home page.

Comment: yeah i got it working using the code shown on here, based on using ip in the db, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ericsson

Working Solution

the try and except does need a clean up but hope this can help others

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print('is_authenticated')
        return redirect('home')
    form = LoginForm()
    if current_user.is_authenticated == False:
        try:
            print(request.remote_addr)
            user = User.query.filter_by(ip=request.remote_addr).first()
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect('home')
        except:
            ''
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(ip)
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect('home')
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check email and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)
```